# How does points calculation work in Nation Red barricades?

Tags: nation-red

For me is not clear how the points calculation works in "Barricades" mode of Nation Red.

I resisted 20 minutes and did 1800 frags, but I got less points than the player that come before me on Steam ladder that resisted 10 minutes and got 1000 frags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difficulty slider you can adjust pre-game which affects the number of points that are awarded per kill. The slider goes from 0% - 100%: The slider level determines the percentage of points that are awarded.

From [this thread where the question is noted(albeit mistyped)](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1400721):

> Ran 2 games on Barricade warehouse for 5 mins. One at 100% difficulty and the other at 50% (default)
>
> At 100% i scored 21.5 million
>
> At 50% i scored 14.1 million
>
> Both i had auto XP as first perk.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Okay, so, [again from the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1681123):

> I can probably guess what caused that: the tweaking of the difficulty level and the amount of Xp you get per kill.
>
> When Nation Red was released a lot of
> players said it was too easy to
> collect perks: The difficulty level
> was then increased (apart from new
> perks, bosses, weapons, etc. which of
> course also affects scoring) so it
> became harder to beat existing scores.
>
> Players felt NR became a bit too hard:
> the Xp per kill was increased.
>
> So what you're seeing is some scores
> achieved with an 'older' version of
> the game and some with the current
> version.
>
> In the end the game is constantly
> evolving with new weapons, perks,
> player classes, etc. It's impossible
> to keep the scoring perfectly equal
> (some new boss may be a bit harder
> than others, some new perk may be a
> bit too powerful, etc.)
>
> Resetting leaderboards is one fix but
> I've tried to resist doing this until
> no new perks/bosses/player
> classes/weapons, etc. are added.
>
> The next update will be a major one
> with 3-4 player coop and the final
> player classes. If a leaderboard reset
> is needed, that may be the best time.
>
> Having said that, if you want to beat
> existing scores:
>
> - You get a lot more Xp playing on higher difficulty than lower
> - You get more Auto Experience (Perk) on higher than lower difficulty
> - On higher difficulty, zombies spawn more often = more Xp.
>
> So beating existing scores is very
> possible but maybe try not to
> investigate the exact playing times,
> etc. when comparing scores.

Hopefully *this* helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to increase to 100% but it happened the same. I reached position 400th now after 56 minutes of play, but the one before me played 30 minutes and did the same points I did

Comment: Now is clear, I hope they will reset leaderboards so. Thank you